# Meteor Typescript: export class defined in lib folder

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript, gulp

I am trying `Meteor` with `Typescript` and I am beginner in this stack.

I have a class defined inside `lib` folder like this:

```
// lib/base.ts
module base {
  export class Person {
    name: string
  }
}
```

I want to use this class in my `client` code somewhere like this `function (p: Person) { ... }`.

**Try 1** I tried using this class with `reference comment` (`/// <reference path="..." />`) but this will build this class again in my `client` directory.

**Try 2** Built declaration file. But got `base is not defined` error.

```
//base.d.ts
declare module base {
  class Person {
    name: string
  }
}
```

How, can I make this class available to `client` side without building again in `client` or `server` directory? 
Note: I am using `gulp-tsc` in three tasks separately for `server`, `client` and `lib` exactly like this [repo](https://github.com/dataflows/meteor-typescript-utils-example)

Comment: How is the client supposed to use that code if it can't have its own copy of it? Should it download it from the server?

Comment: AFAIK, shared files are kept in some shared directory like `lib` in my case, isn't it? I want it to be able to use in `server` also, so I kept it there. My `shared` gulp task creates `[root]/lib/shared.js` for codes in `lib` directory. so there stands no point of creating another same codes inside `client` directory. Meteor first loads files from my `lib` directory, I could find in my browser too but only could not access with same package name

Comment: Is this because of IIFE made my module hidden?